# Sprockets can't find angular.js even after adding node_modules to asset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm using rails 5.0.3

I've added npm to this project at the applications' root.

In order to load node_modules into the asset pipeline I've added the following line to config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

Then I've included angular in my application.js manifest file like so:

```
//= require angular/angular.js
//= require app.js
//= require_tree ./ng/constants
//= require_tree ./ng/services
//= require_tree ./ng/controllers
```

I've tried a number of variations such as:

```
require_directory angular
require_tree angular
require angular/angular.js
require angular
```

This DOES work locally, but when I push to heroku it says:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'angular/angular.js' with type 'application/javascript'
 ...... [lists all the asset paths Sprockets has searched including node_modules]
/tmp/build_93a7b2eb7cc158c5d30b242da36b56ac/node_modules
```

It seems that there is something happening when the application is loading the assets in Heroku for production than when it's run locally in development, but what is it?

I've also tried precompiling everything in my manifest file by including this line from config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js )
```

The way that this works in Heroku for production is by first doing:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Why must I precompile these assets before I push to master? How can I make this part of the default process?

Comment: Were you able to find out the cause of this?

Comment: I haven't found the reason yet. I've just continued to precompile the assets manually. @cavneb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we solved this is by installing the webpacker gem and running `rails webpacker:install`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with assets precompile on Rails 7.0 with esbuild as javascript build tool. So sprockets couldn't see dependencies required by esbuild and installed in node_modules by yarn.

```bash
$: bundle exec rake assets:precompile

rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/zh/app/assets/audios
  /home/zh/app/assets/builds
  /home/zh/app/assets/config
  /home/zh/app/assets/images
  /home/zh/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/zh/vendor/assets/javascripts
```

So fix was the following:
edit `config/application.rb`
append

```rb
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    #...
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
    #...
  end
end
```